# Does smooth and flat shading only effect view-port look or render too?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

I need to know before I render project and I am not sure about this!

Comment: It affects both.But for things like this you can make a test render and find out.

Answer (score 1):

Both smooth and flat shading will effect the final render of your project. Good Luck!